# Pandas data frame category-ish column values to columns with boolean-ish int values

Tags: python, pandas

i have a category-ish pandas data frame column of type string like:

```
MY_CATEGORY
X
X
Y
Z
Z
```

i want to make it:

```
X   Y   Z
1   0   0
1   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   1
0   0   1
```

how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.get_dummies`.

```
import pandas

# your data
# ====================================
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df

  MY_CATEGORY
0           X
1           X
2           Y
3           Z
4           Z

# processing
# ====================================
pd.get_dummies(df.MY_CATEGORY)

   X  Y  Z
0  1  0  0
1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  1
4  0  0  1
```

Comment: Works! Great! Thanks!

I will accept your answer as soon as I am allowed to. ;-)